# How to make dynamic widgets in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, widget

I want to make a dynamic widget to show votes on a particular topic.

I want to make a copy/paste widget so that other site can show vote via copy/paste  html/js/css code provided by me.

It's similar to how we use js/html code for showing bookmark & share tool.

Can anyone give any ideas how to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: write api\rest interface on your server, have widget code interact with it. Broad answer for broad question

Comment: Dagon: Can u please give me a link where i can see such example code?

Comment: only by using google, so i may as well leave that to you. specific questions get much better answers

Comment: widget on platforms like Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you nead to use a swf file.
Javascript deny it for security reasons.
View this Link:

[Zero Clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to say, you can have a php class for taking votes for a particular topic from database. And a controller class that calls this method. With a simple xmlhttprequest or just using simple post function on JQuery, you can get the votes and show them in your html. If you provide more details i can provide more detailed solution.